# How to import and make use of a package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I will like to know how to import a new package from third party in flutter and call it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of packages on [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/).

To import it just open any package and navigate to the `Installing` Tab.

[image]

Then you just need to copy this sentence to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

[image]

Paste line under `dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml`. Note that spaces is very important so make it start just under `flutter:` when pasting.

[image]

Save changes in `pubspec.yaml` and it will install the packages automatically. If it doesn't install run `flutter pub get` from command line to install the package manually.

Lastly do not forget to import the library at the top of the file by using the line provided here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the library in `pubspec.yaml`, then run `flutter packages get` in your IDE terminal.

Ex:

I'm using [toast](https://pub.dev/packages/toast) package, so I will define this in pubspec.yaml

```
toast: ^0.1.5
```